# VSS2GIT ERROR:The process cannot access the file data\name.dat because it is being used by another process

Tags: git, vb6, visual-sourcesafe

When we are trying to migrate VSS VB6 code to GIT using VSS2GIT tool it is showing error as below:
"***The process cannot access the file 'D:\VSSDatabase\data\name.dat' because it is being used by another process.***"

Answer (score 1):

Use handle utility for discover who lock file: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely since you are opening the repo by Microsoft Visual SourceSafe concurrently.

You need to close(/disconnect) VSS from the repo before conducting VSS2Git.